# .net 2010 shortcut to paste a code in starting of every methods

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shortcut

I have to add a using block statement in all the DAO methods. Ther are about 15 class files and each file has 50 methods. Is there any short cut to paste the below line of code in the begining of all the methods ?

Using (datacontext db = new datacontext())
{

}

I know to use ctrl+K+S to add code snippet. but still i have to manually paste in all the methods.

is there any other way to do it

Thanks,
Jebli.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check the T4 engine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

It's the best way to automate certain coding tasks.